# DNS issue with Ubuntu. Url request works fine in MacOSX, but fails in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, travis-ci

A nodeJS [script](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/grunt-appc-coverage/blob/master/lib/appc-coverage.js#L75) that invokes `require('request').post()` has been written. This script works fine in MacOSX (Travis) however fails in Ubuntu (Travis). The NodeJS 'https' module was also tested to eliminate extraneous variables that could contribute to the error. However this did not work either.

```
/**
* Upload the data to the coverage server
*/
exports.upload = function (data, callback) {
    var url = SERVER + '/v1/coverage';
    request.post(url, {
        form : {
        type : 'grunt-appc-coverage',
        data: data
        },
        json: true,
        agentOptions: false
    }, function (err, response, body) {
        console.log(err, response, body);
        ....
        return callback(null, SUCCESS_UPLOAD);
    });
};
```

This is what i get from the logs for Ubuntu.

```
REQUEST make request https://coverage.appcelerator.com/v1/coverage

{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND coverage.appcelerator.com]

code: 'ENOTFOUND',

errno: 'ENOTFOUND',

syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

hostname: 'coverage.appcelerator.com' } undefined undefined
```

The results can be seen here
 - [Ubuntu](https://travis-ci.org/appcelerator-modules/grunt-appc-coverage/jobs/54615710)
 - MacOSX (Could not post link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that CNAME is to spec:

```
$ dig +short coverage.appcelerator.com
https://454bcc35e4c9b0c030c89b311b4322330d84fa3b.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com.
ec2-54-244-121-14.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
54.244.121.14
$
```

That looks broken.  Specifically, that first CNAME looks broken: Its value should be a domain name, not a URL.

… or have I not been keeping up with DNS? :)

ETA: No, I've checked a few resources, and they agree CNAME must hold a domain name and nothing else.  So, yeah, that DNS record needs to be replaced with a sensible one.